# Ensure preprocessor define does not change value

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When implementing Annex K of the C standard (Bounds-checking Interfaces), there is the following requirement:

The extensions specified in this annex can be "requested" to be declared by defining `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to `1`, and requested to *not* be declared by defining that to `0`.

Then there is this paragraph:

> Within a preprocessing translation unit, __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ _ shall be deﬁned identically for all inclusions of any headers from subclause K.3. If __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ _ is deﬁned differently for any such inclusion, the implementation shall issue a diagnostic as if a preprocessor error directive were used.

**I wonder how to implement this.** I went ahead and naïvely wrote this (to be included in each affected header):

```
#ifndef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
  #ifdef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
    #error __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ undefined when it was defined previously.
  #endif
#else
  #ifdef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
    #if __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ != __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
      #error __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ defined to different value from previous include.
    #endif
  #else
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
  #endif
#endif
```

This (of course) does not work for a variety of reasons:

- Does not catch the case when `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` is not defined for the first include, but defined for the second (which should also be caught with an `#error`)
- The `#define` does not take the *value* of `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` (prefixing `#` would take the symbol as string, going through symbol2value(...) would take the `1` as string).
- ...

...but if taken as pseudocode it showcases the logic behind it.

I am not that well-versed with more intricate preprocessor business like this, as you are usually told to stay away from macro magic. **There has to be a way to implement the quoted requirement; it just doesn't "click" for me.**

Any ideas?

---

To complete the [mcve], put the above code into `header.h`, and this in `testme.c`:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 0
#include "header.h"
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include "header.h"

int main() {}
```

This *should* trigger the "different value" error message.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to activate it via a compiler option -D__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__=1 ?

Comment: @user6556709: That would make it a bit difficult to (erroneously) redefine it for the second include, which was the point of the example code.

Comment: you can redefine defines from the compiler in the same way as usual defines. Btw. You should first #undef a define before giving it a new value. Otherwise your compiler should warn you.

Comment: @user6556709: GCC gives a warning for an `#undef` as well. Could we please focus on the topic of the question instead of discussing code style of the example?

Comment: I don't think this is intended to be implemented with "macro magic", but rather by the compiler/preprocessor itself (which can keep a global registry of defines eg., and notice changes easily). Are you asking how a real compiler might implement this ? Or are you asking how to do it with "macro magic" ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I am implementing a [standard C library](http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de). A portable solution would be perfect, a solution that works with e.g. GCC and / or clang would be acceptable.

Comment: Based on the quoted paragraph, are we sure including the header with __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ undefined is even valid? Makes little sense to me having a "boolean" with three states - 0, 1, undfined... Then again, C standard folks aren't perfect

Comment: @Andreas: Behavior is implementation-defined if `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` is not set, and well-defined for the values 0 and 1, with additional values reserved for future use. The error behavior for *changing* values is well-defined though, so that is what would be expected from a standard lib like mine.

Comment: @DevSolar Implemention defined is the best if you are making the implementation - anything is correct ;) I think I have an idea of how to do this...

Comment: @Andreas Implementation-defined is especially helpful *during* implementation, as you are not required to provide *all* the functions specified in the annex. ;-) Eventually, though, I'll of course aim for full compliance. Thanks for thinking about this, I drew a blank...

Comment: I think it is actually the programmer problem not yours. If the programmer is not consistent that is his problem.

Comment: @P__J__ : "...*the implementation* shall issue a diagnostic as if a preprocessor error directive were used". This is the bounds-checking annex. It shifts responsibility to the implementation, not only regarding this specific issue but with many other things as well (re-entrancy, runtime constraints checking etc.). Anyway... that quote from the standard makes it *my* problem.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a logic problem, and someone else will attack it (and I have to be to bed soon), so I'll quickly leave this partial... don't define your `PREVIOUS` macro in terms of the current value; define it as literally `0`, `1`, or some token (`-1` we'll say to represent undefined).  Macros aren't variables; they store replacement lists, not what that replacement list would expand to, and especially here you want your storage to be literally what you found (so that next time the `EXT` is defined, you don't simply think you're equal to it).

Comment: To be clear, I mean `#define PREV CURRENT` is a trap; that `CURRENT` is 1 when the definition is made is of no consequence... once CURRENT is defined as 0 for the second include and this macro is used as a value, it will expand to 0.  You want `#if CURRENT==1/#define PREV 1`; this way, if `CURRENT` is redefined to 0 and you compare to PREV, it will truly be not equal.

Answer (score 4):

@HWalters did set me on the right track:

```
#ifndef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
  #ifdef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
    #if __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ != -1
      #error __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ undefined when it was defined earlier.
    #endif
  #else
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ -1
  #endif
#else
  #ifdef __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
    #if __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ != __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__
      #error __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ redefined from previous value.
    #endif
  #else
    #if __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ == 0
      #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ 0
    #elif __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ == 1
      #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ 1
    #else
      /* Values other than 0,1 reserved for future use */
      #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ -2
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

The "thinko" was this line:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_PREVIOUS__ __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
```

Defining the "previous" to an actual value instand of another token makes it work.

The solution is not perfect, though -- all "other" values except 0,1,undefined get lumped together into a single "previous" value (-2), while the letter of the standard says that *any* redefinition should issue a diagnostic.

Comment: I leave the question open in case the "perfect" solution is still "out there".